# Unmarshal XML Comments

Tags: xml, go, comments

I am trying to unmarshal XML from RRD format.

So I create my types etc, etc. which I am able to get the values from.

But there are comments in the XML in this format `<!-- 2017/01/01 -->` and I need to extract this date. Is there any way of accessing this in GO ?

Thanks.

Updated question:

Okay I did it works, but I want to split the comments into array.

For example I have the following XML.

```
<database>
<!-- Random Info. -->
<row>10101</row>
<!-- Random Info2 . -->
<row>10102</row>
</database>
```

So I have the following.

```
type Database struct {
          Comment string `xml:",comment"`   
          Row []string  `xml:"row"`
    }
```

Now when I print the row data I get it as an array whereas the comment is a string.
I tried to make it an array but it throws an error cannot convert.
panic: reflect.Set: value of type []uint8 is not assignable to type []string

Obviously, I can split the string and get what I want. But is there any quicker way of doing this when creating type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried  https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal?

> If the XML element contains comments, they are accumulated in  the
>   first struct field that has tag ",comment".  The struct  field may
>   have type []byte or string. If there is no such  field, the comments
>   are discarded.

Here's usage example: https://golang.org/src/encoding/xml/example_test.go

```
type Person struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"person"`
    ...
    Comment   string   `xml:",comment"`
}
```

Comment: One more question is there anyway to break up the Comments into array for example Row below breaks up into array where as comments if I try [] will give me an error type Database struct {
     Comment string `xml:",comment"` 
   Row []string  `xml:"row"`
 }

Comment: @NoName2 what question? Try to use it alike

Comment: I think no, they are accumulated in one field. But you may split at some meaningful places.